# Redirecting User After Iframe Source Change?

Tags: javascript, iframe, html

I am coding in javascript, i know its not a neat solution.

Here is my code. I am using a Overflow Iframe. I want user to be redirected after iframe source change. But my code in not redirecting user after iframe source change.

**Please note**: I want the iframe to be placed on a page And I want to check history of link inside iframe to detect iframe source change not page source change. I have no control over content of iframe. Its a cross domaine iframe. For Example 
http://freestarbucksgiftcard4u.blogspot.in/2012/04/stalk-overflow-testing.html

Also, the link inside iframe is random, so i can't be determined. I can just compare it with history to detect change.

**Iframe code:**

```
    <div class="offerlink"
 style="overflow: hidden; width: 467px; height: 321px; position: relative;" id="i_div"><iframe name="i_frame" src="http://www.villanovau.com/form/pm/070809_vu_pm_save/?source=193664zv1&utm_source=Quigo&utm_medium=PPC&utm_campaign=VU_PM&WT.mc_id=4321" style="border: 0pt none ; left: -518px; top: -274px; position: absolute; width: 1242px; height: 616px;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

**Javscript code:**

```
var Delay = 0;
        var AppearDelay = 10;
        var oldHistLength = history.length;

    var once_per_session=1;
    var unknown=true;

    function setcookie() {
    if (unknown==false){
    document.cookie="alerted=yes"
    }
    }  

    function get_cookie(Name) {
    var search = Name + "="
    var returnvalue = "";
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
    if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
    offset += search.length
    // set index of beginning of value
    end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
    // set index of end of cookie value
    if (end == -1)
    end = document.cookie.length;
    returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
   }
    }
    return returnvalue;
   }

    setInterval ( "checkHistory()", 1000 );


     function checkHistory()
    {
   if (oldHistLength != history.length)
   {
   redirect();
   oldHistLength = history.length;
   }
   }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.offerlink').click(function()
        {
            setTimeout('redirect()', Delay*1000);
        });

    });
```

This solution is not working for me. Please help me in debugging this javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the contents generated in the iframe, you can just do like this:

```
<body onload="top.location.href='newpath.html'">
```

or a nicer scripted version

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){top.location.href='newpath.html';}
</script>
```

in the

best,
Michael

Comment: Edited question, please do suggest some other solution.

Comment: Well first of all the setInterval uses a function reference to execute. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/BwmSB/

Comment: Allso, why all the cookie stuff? Do you need to persist it over several pages? or the single page?

Comment: Well, i am doing is for a iframe on a page. User Click a Button inside iframe, then he is take to other page inside iframe. This is what i want to detect using my function and cookie stuff.